# Compactness proof of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact. Show that $$X \times Y=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\in X, y\in Y\}$$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt:

Since $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then this implies that it is closed and bounded thus for all $x\in X$ and for all $y\in Y$ there exists an $M>0$ such that $|(x,y)|\le M$. From this, how can I show that $X \times Y$ is bounded? And for showing that it is closed, I know I have to show $\mathbb{R}^2 - (X\times Y)$ is open, but how can I show that?

Comment: Take an open cover of XxY and construct a finite subcover from those guaranteed by assumption on X,Y...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 That is one way I learned on my own, but the way we learned to prove compactness is to show that it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Have it your way! I learned to show it by the definition :)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Lol thanks anyways. When finals are over with I am going to try to relearn everything with better technique and subcovers are going to be the first things!

Comment: It could be rather general if we come into the situation of topology spaces. The proof is similar in such a way: if $Y$ is compact and a open set of $X\times Y$ contains $x_0\times Y$, then there's a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $V$ covers $U\times Y$. For detailed information, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma) or Munkres' topology.

Comment: @FrankScience thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X$ bounded implies for all $x\in X$, $|x|\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$. This means for all $x\in X$ $x\in [-M,M]$. Similarly for all $y\in Y$ we have $y\in [-N,N]$. Therefore for all $(x,y)\in X \times Y$ we have $(x,y)\in [-M,M]\times [-N,N]$. Therefore bounded.

To show closedness take a converging sequence $(x_n,y_n)$.This sequence will converge in the Euclidean metric iff $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge. However since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, the limit points will be contained in $X$ and $Y$. This means, if $x_n\rightarrow x$, $y_n\rightarrow y$, we have $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ implying $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, implying limit of $(x_n,y_n)$, an arbitrary sequence in $X\times Y$ is contained in the Cartesian Product.

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to show that it is closed using the fact $\mathbb{R}^2 - (X\times Y)$ is open, how will I be able to do that?

Comment: take any point in $\mathbb{R}^2-(X\times Y)$. You WTS this point is an interior point. Suppose it is not. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ you are able to find another point within the $\epsilon$-disk s.t. that point is in $X\times Y$. Notice that the point that you began with, being in $\mathbb{R}^2-(X\times Y)$ satisfies that at least one of the coordinates is not in $X$ (or in $Y$). However, this means one of the coordinates is in $\mathbb{R}-X$ (or Y) which you know is open. Contradiction should be immediate from this.

Comment: you're welcome. nice question